# what's does System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"\D") .Replace(value, string.Empty) value = value.TrimStart('1'); mean in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

```
public static string FormatTelephoneNumber(string value)
    {
        value = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"\D")
            .Replace(value, string.Empty);
        value = value.TrimStart('1');

        if (value.Length == 7)
            return Convert.ToInt64(value).ToString("+234 # ### ###");
        if (value.Length == 9)
            return Convert.ToInt64(value).ToString("+233 ### ### ###");
            return value;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`new Regex(@"\D").Replace(value, string.Empty)` will create a regular expression that matches any non-digit characters (`\D`) and then will replace all matches in `value` string with `string.Empty`.
`value = value.TrimStart('1')` will remove all occurrences of '1' symbol from beginning of the string, so, for instance, `"111blablabla"` will become `"blablabla"` and `"1232123"` will become `"232123"`.

[Regex.Replace on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[String.TrimStart on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimstart%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)